# Problems inserting data into the database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem inserting data into my database although it is successfully inserted but then the data inserted into the database turn into integers.

```
<?php
//connect to database
include "databaseconnection.php";   

?>

<body bgcolor="#e5edf8">

<form name="addform" method="post" action="../insert.php">
<table width="1110" height="184" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
  <td width="393" height="28"><strong> TICKET NO :
    <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM troubleticket");
        $record = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        echo '<input type="text" name="ticketnofld" readonly value="    '.$record['ticketno'].' " >'; 
     ?>
  </strong>
  </td>

  <td width="717"> <strong>TECHNICAL NAME :
  <?php 
        echo "<select  name='techname' type='text'>";
        echo '<option id="0">'.'--Select technical Name--'.'</option>';
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM technical");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
               {
                echo '<option value=" '.$record['ID'].'">'.$record['FNAME']. '</option>';
               }        
        echo '</select>';
    ?>

  </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><strong>COMPANY NAME : 
     <?php 
        echo "<select name='companyname' type='text'>";
        echo '<option id="0">'.'--Select Company Name--'.'</option>';
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
               {
                echo '<option value=" '.$record['ID'].'">'.$record['NAME']. '</option>';
               }        
        echo '</select>';
     ?>
  </select> 
  </strong></td>
  <td><strong>TYPE OF SERVICE :
   <?php 
        echo " <select name='typeofservice' type='text'>";
        echo '<option id="0">'.'--Select type of service--'.'</option>';
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM typeofservice");
        while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
               {
                echo '<option value=" '.$record['tosid'].'">'.$record['typeofservice']. '</option>';
               }        
        echo '</select>';

    ?>
  </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><p><strong>PROBLEM :<textarea type='text' rows="10" cols="100" name="problemfld" id="problemfld"> </textarea>
     </strong></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="Addbutton" value="ADD" >
                  <input type="button" name="Cancelbutton" value="CANCEL" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and this is the insert.php

```
 <?php
 $con=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","ojt") or die('Could not reach the database'.mysql_error());

 $techname=isset($_POST['techname']);
 $companyname=isset($_POST['companyname']);
 $typeofservice=isset($_POST['typeofservice']);
 $problem=isset($_POST['problemfld']);

 $techname=stripslashes($techname);
 $companyname=stripslashes($companyname);
 $typeofservice=stripslashes($typeofservice);
 $problem=stripslashes($problem);

 $techname=mysql_real_escape_string($techname);
 $companyname=mysql_real_escape_string($companyname);
 $typeofservice=mysql_real_escape_string($typeofservice);
 $problem=mysql_real_escape_string($problem);   

 $sql="INSERT INTO `ojt`.`troubleticket` (`ticketno`, `technicalname`, `services`, `problem`, `companyname`, `remarks`) VALUES (' ','$techname', '$typeofservice', '$problem', '$companyname', 'NEW')";
$query=mysql_query($sql,$con);
if($query)
{
echo '1 Data Added';
}
else
{
echo 'Unsuccessfully Saved';
}
?>
```

Comment: MySQL is deprecate in PHP 5.5.x, consider switching to MySQLi.

Comment: Definitely something to do with `isset` in `$techname=isset($_POST['techname']);` etc.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `isset` returns a boolean, the proper way would be,  
`if(isset($_POST['techname'])) $techname = $_POST['techname'];`

Comment: This whole thing could've easily been avoided, including a rewrite if PDO were used or prepared statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing integers instead of data, check this code:

```
 $techname=isset($_POST['techname']);
 $companyname=isset($_POST['companyname']);
 $typeofservice=isset($_POST['typeofservice']);
 $problem=isset($_POST['problemfld']);
```

it sets variables to `1`, as result of `isset`

you need to change it to:

```
 $techname=isset($_POST['techname']) ? $_POST['techname'] : '';
 $companyname=isset($_POST['companyname']) ? $_POST['companyname'] : '';
 $typeofservice=isset($_POST['typeofservice']) ? $_POST['typeofservice'] : '';
 $problem=isset($_POST['problemfld']) ? $_POST['problemfld'] : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a problem inserting data into my database although it is
>   successfully inserted but then the data inserted into the database
>   turn into integers.

Yes, because that is what you have in your `<option>` tags. For example, here is the select list for “Company Name”:

```
 <?php 
    echo "<select name='companyname' type='text'>";
    echo '<option id="0">'.'--Select Company Name--'.'</option>';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
           {
            echo '<option value=" '.$record['ID'].'">'.$record['NAME']. '</option>';
           }        
    echo '</select>';
 ?>
```

The data being passed by the form is `$record['ID']` and not `$record['NAME']`. So you would have to change that to something like this:

```
 <?php 
    echo "<select name='companyname' type='text'>";
    echo '<option id="">'.'--Select Company Name--'.'</option>';
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM client");
    while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
           {
            echo '<option value=" '.$record['NAME'].'">'.$record['NAME']. '</option>';
           }        
    echo '</select>';
 ?>
```

Note how I changed the `<option id="0">` to be `<option id="">` and set the `'<option value=" '.$record['NAME'].'">'`.

Also, you have this:

```
 $techname=isset($_POST['techname']);
 $companyname=isset($_POST['companyname']);
 $typeofservice=isset($_POST['typeofservice']);
 $problem=isset($_POST['problemfld']);
```

And `isset` just returns a `0` or `1`. So it is just checking if the `$_POST` value exists and not much else. To quickly test, just change it to this:

```
 $techname=$_POST['techname'];
 $companyname=$_POST['companyname'];
 $typeofservice=$_POST['typeofservice'];
 $problem=$_POST['problemfld'];
```

But looking at the repetitive nature of your code, I would recommend condensing it to this instead:

```
// Set the database connection.
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","ojt") or die('Could not reach the database'.mysql_error());

// Set an array of post values.
$post_array = array('techname', 'companyname', 'typeofservice', 'problemfld');

// Roll through the post values, validate & assign them.
foreach ($post_array as $post_key => $post_value) {
  $$post_key = '';
  if (isset($_POST[$post_key])) {
    $$post_key = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST[$post_key]));
  }
}

// Set the query.
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ojt`.`troubleticket` (`ticketno`, `technicalname`, `services`, `problem`, `companyname`, `remarks`) VALUES (' ','$techname', '$typeofservice', '$problemfld', '$companyname', 'NEW')";

// Run the query.
$query = mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Check if the query ran.
if ($query) {
  echo '1 Data Added';
}
else {
  echo 'Unsuccessfully Saved';
}
```

And yes, `mysql_*` extensions are depreciated in PHP 5.3 & 5.4 and will be eliminated in version 5.5 so you should learn about `mysqli_*` usage. Which is similar to `mysql_*`, but up to you to handle.